# Paperclip with symlinks on NFS, no routes matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, paperclip, symlink, nfs

I’ve a strange behaviour on a fairly complex Rails 5 project.

My app runs on a server with Phusion Passenger 5 behind NGINX and deploys are managed with Capistrano 3.

Everything works fine except one thing, the **paperclip** gem.

Currently paperclip can upload and save files, storing file names on the database but when the app use *GET* method on an image url the result is a **404** .

The rails error is *No route matches [GET]* with the url of the file.

On my dev machine everything works fine.

Currently the system folder where Paperclip store files is a Symlink to an NFS disk mounted outside the application public folder.

I’m fairly sure that problem resides on the NFS mount or symlink, because if I use a local folder I have no problems.

Does anyone ever tried a similar configuration?

Does the NFS mount needs to be mounted or configured in some way?

Comment: I'm thinking the file urls should point to somewhere outside you rails application so that NGINX serves them directly without invoking your rails application. https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/

Comment: We tried with a symlink on a same path folder, everything works fine if the folder is not an NFS mount.